# Prove that $4^{(p-1)/2}\equiv 1\pmod p$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

If $p$ is a prime of the form $4k+3$, prove that $4^{\frac{p-1}{2}}\equiv 1\pmod p$.

I was solving a problem and it came down to this. I have no idea how to prove it, I have tried. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: You are making things harder than they need to be.  Think Fermat's Little Thm.

Comment: Also, this only needs $p$ to be odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $4^{\frac{p-1}2}=(2^{2})^{\frac{p-1}2}=2^{p-1}$

Comment: Use Fermat's Little Theorem.

Answer (score 2):

There surely is another way to prove it, and they might be getting at quadratic reciprocity here, but Fermat's little theorem provides the simplest way to prove this particular question. If $p$ is a prime number, of whatever form, and $a$ is a number coprime to $p$, then $a^{p - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$. (I won't give a proof of Fermat's little theorem here, but it's easy enough to find from multiple sources).

All that we need to do now is rewrite $4^{\frac{p - 1}{2}}$ in such a way that allows us to apply Fermat's little theorem. Note that $4^x = 2^{2x}$. And voila! $4^{\frac{p - 1}{2}} = 2^{p - 1}$, and since 2 is clearly coprime to $p = 4k + 3$, it follows that $2^{p - 1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ as asserted.